# Is it possible to use functional routes in spring webmvc for handler returning Mono<ServerResponse>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In spring mvc, you can have endpoint returning Mono/Flux from project-reactor like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
class Application {

    @GetMapping("foo")
    fun foo(): Mono<String> {
        return Mono.just("foo")
    }
}
```

So if I had some library written using Flux/Mono streams, I could use it. So far, so good.

However, since version 5.2.0, spring is planning to introduce webflux's functional router style endpoint mapping, I would like to use it to. For simple endpoint, it could look like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {

    @Bean
    fun mvcRoutes() =
        router {
            GET("/foo"){ ServerResponse.ok().body("foo")}
        }

}
```

Now, you could think, that everything would be ok, if I write everything as non-blocking with reactor, and you could use the the library in both webmvc and webflux applications. It should be just as easy as switching the dependency from spring-boot-starter-webflux to spring-boot-starter-web.

However it isn't. Webmvc application seems to be ignoring router function bean created with webflux's class base. Ok, so let's configure the route again and have only the handler service shared. Oops, you cant. The handler function returns Mono and you would think that calling the block would return ServerResponse and you're there. But, you aren't.

Webmvc's RouterFunction, ServerResponse, ServerRequest, etc are totally different classes from the one of webflux, so you cannot reuse the handler service written for webflux.

As the non-blocking code was reusable in spring webmvc 5.0.0, it is strange for me that for the new functional routes for webmvc, it would not be possible. Am I missing something? Is there any way for sharing non-blocking reactor functionality over webmvc and webflux applications while taking advantage of the new functional routes definition?

Note: I am using kotlin, but the problem is the same for java.

Comment: RouterFunction is dedicated for webflux framework. There is no option to use it with springmvc.

Comment: spring is introducing this feature in 5.2.0 version. See [link](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/10/spring-framework-5-2-0-m1-available-now)